# Html structure affecting element cloning

Tags: jquery, html, clone

So, I have bunch of elements inside parent elements:

```
<div class="copyFrom">
    <div class="copyThese">copyThese1</div>
</div>
<div class="copyFrom">
    <div class="copyThese">copyThese2</div>
</div>
```

Also, I have *separate* `.Parent` element in which I append `.copyHere` elements to correspond the amount of `.copyFrom` elements

```
<div class="Parent">
    <div class="copyHere"></div>
    <div class="copyHere"></div>
</div>
```

Aaaalso, Inside `.copyHere` I clone every separate `.copyThese` elements

```
<div class="Parent">
    <div class="copyHere">
        <div class="copyThese">copyThese1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="copyHere">
        <div class="copyThese">copyThese2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Now, the problem is:**

For some reason, if `.Parent` is *below* all the `.copyFrom` elements The `.copyThese` elements are cloned in just fine.

But.. If `.Parent` element is *above* The `.copyFrom` elements, the cloning of `.copyThese` elements goes haywire.

**I need to have `.Parent` element both above and below.** (  Without weird cloning problems.)

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/mZhUG/2/ - Above - **Correct**

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/mZhUG/3/ - Below - **Problem**

Comment: very well formatted question :)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what html you would like to create

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I'm not sure you can help me if you didn't find that out from the question..

Comment: @Lollero i got it at last! :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti To quote fearofawhackplanet: "it happens to all of us!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are adding a new `.copyThese` element each iteration.

`copyThese.eq( copyHere ).clone().appendTo( $(this) );`

You are cloning the `nth` element, but you have added `n` elements above, so even though your indexer is incrementing you are still cloning the same div.

```
$('.copyHere').each(function(){
    var copyHere = $(this).index();

    // you re-initialise this array within each loop, 
    // elements are added to the start of the array each time
    var copyThese = $('.copyThese');

    copyThese.eq( copyHere ).clone().appendTo( $(this) );
});
```

change to this and it works:

```
copyThese = $('.copyThese');

$('.copyHere').each(function(){
    var copyHere = $(this).index();
    copyThese.eq( copyHere ).clone().appendTo( $(this) );
});
```

do you see the difference? I'm maybe not explaining it very well but hopefully you can see the problem.

Comment: Yes, I feel such a fool asking a question that really has quite a simple problem that I've been trying to solve for hours.

Comment: @Lollero it happens to all of us!

Answer (score 3):

you should do:

```
  var copyThese = $('.copyFrom .copyThese');
```

because you are adding `.copyThese` elements at every iteration and keep cloning the same element. This doesn't happen if you add the elements After the one already present in the dom and so the problem is present only if `.parent` is prepended

fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mZhUG/4/

Comment: I'm gonna do with fearofawhackplanet's answer, but since this work's and I'm not sure if I have to come back to using this.. I'm gonna give you + 1

Comment: +1 this is a good answer. I was just trying to show where the problem was rather than suggesting an exact answer.